# return value when call service function in Nodejs and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have a function use Service to call the function from server :
Ex:

```
A : function(){
  Service.function().then(function(rs){
    return rs
  })
}
B : function(){
  var rs = this.A()
  console.log('rs: ', rs) // undefined
}
```

In another function i declare one variable to receive value from function A, but value is received is undefined. 
I need help for this issue. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Your `Service.func()` function (`function` is actually a reserved keyword, you can't use it) returns a Promise object, a Promise you need to also return from your custom function, like so:

```
A: function() {
    return Service.func().then(function(rs) { return rs; });
}
```

Then you can use it elsewhere.

Another thing worth noting, `.then(function(rs) { return rs; })` actually doesn't do anything (it will return a promise that resolves with the same value), so you can shorten your code to this:

```
A: function() {
    return Service.func(); // Done!
}
```

Also, if you expect `rs` to be the response object in your second function, you're wrong. What `rs` would be is a **Promise** that resolves to the response object. So `B` should look something like this:

```
B: function() {
    var rs = this.A(); // rs is a promise!
    rs.then(function(realRs) { console.log(realRs); });
}
```